# ListView adding an empty colomn

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have my listView in C#. It should have only one colomn, and also the attribute fo Colomns shows it has only one colomn, but the display shows two:

[image]

The ListView is initiated very simply, using

```
initializeComponenet()
```

which contains following code:

```
        **this.lstDS.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
              this.DirectoryHeader});**

        this.lstDS.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12.75F);
        this.lstDS.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.lstDS.FullRowSelect = true;
        this.lstDS.HideSelection = false;
        this.lstDS.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem[] {
        listViewItem1,
        listViewItem2});
        this.lstDS.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(75, 152);
        this.lstDS.MultiSelect = false;
        this.lstDS.Name = "lstDS";
        this.lstDS.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(203, 138);
        this.lstDS.TabIndex = 37;
        this.lstDS.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
        this.lstDS.View = System.Window
```

if you ask yourself - here's DirectoryHeader:

```
private ColumnHeader DirectoryHeader;
```

But for any reason, it appears as if it has 2 columns.

Any idea what to check?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have two Columns, you have a single Column that doesn't fill the entire width of the Control.

Comment: serious?? OOPS... :) THX

Comment: Note that you can use the auto-size feature, if you want the Column's Header to fill the Control's ClientArea, e.g. `lstDS.AutoResizeColumn(0, ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);` -- Note that the internal method tries to compensate for a non-existing 2 pixels padding. When you have a single column, you'll notice. So you could instead set: `lstDS.Columns[0].Width = lstDS.ClientSize.Width`, so the horizontal Scrollbar won't appear (the Vertical Scrollbar is not part of the ClientArea).